# Twos Complement On A Double

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I perform a twos complement on a double and return a double?

Comment: You don't. Two's complement doesn't make sense on a double (beyond the bit level). Logically you can just apply the minus operator: `-d`

Comment: twos complement on a double doesn't make a lot of sense to me; what's the application?

Comment: I think you should first understand how numbers (bit strings) are represented. http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html objects of type double (double precision) are represented in a completely different way than integers (twos complement). This is why your question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do the two's complement of the internal bit representation of the double, you can use the [`BitConverter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx).

Something like:

```
double x = 12345.6;
Int64 bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(x);
bits = ~bits + 1;
x = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits);
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, though...

Answer (score -1):

You might need to cast to a long and then do the twos complement and cast back:

```
double x = 1245.1;
long l = (long)x;
l=~l; l++; /* complement followed by + 1 */
x = (double)l;
```

I didn't test this, but hopefully it gets you on the right track.

Edit: Since you cannot cast from double to long with bit representation then you might need to do something like:

```
double x = 1234.5;
ulong l;
unsigned char * d = (unsigned char *) &x;
l = (ulong)(*d);
l=~l; l++;
d = (unsigned char *) &l;
x = (double)(*d);
```

Again untested...

Comment: unary complement is not defined for doubles.

Comment: Also, you need to do `l = ~l;`, not just `~l;`.

Comment: And casting between `long` and `double` uses the values, not the internal bit representation.